# Arrow key pressed while shift key is held down

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, switch-statement, readonly

I have a [Sudoku](https://www.google.com/search?q=what+is+sudoku&oq=what+is+sudoku&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3j69i65.2135j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) puzzle and I want to make it so the user can press the shift key and hold it down while they use the arrow keys to move up and down between cells. The cells that are already set are `<input>` tags like the rest, but they have the `readonly` attribute. Each cell has a class of 'puzzle_cells' and an id starting with a 'c' followed directly by the row number they are in, a '-', and then the cell number.

So, the third cell down, fifth from the left would have an id of 'c3-5'. Every cell has an id, so I'm thinking the inputs that are editable would have an attribute something like this `onkeyup="shiftArrows(this)"`. My question is what do I put in `shiftArrows()`?

It probably would start with something like:

```
var input_id = $(this).attr('id');
```

but then I have to test if an arrow key is being pressed while the shift key is down. If `shift+down` is pressed or `shift+up` and the cell directly above or below it is `'readonly'`, then it would go to the right one and check it again. If that is `'readonly'`, it would go to the left two, and would keep checking like that. if `shift+right` is pressed it would keep going to the right until if finds an empty one, or jump to the next line if it has to. Same thing for `shift+left`.

Anyway, I could probably do that, but what I don't know is how to test if a arrow is pressed while the shift key is held down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this handle what you're after?

```
if (event.shiftKey && event.which == 38) { 
  //shift was down when up arrow pressed
}
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stroz/hrQEX/3/

Comment: can i put multiple function in an `onkeyup` attribute?

Comment: Take a look at my Fiddle, it's handling the different keypresses

Comment: It's not working for me. Also, use may want to use event.which instead of event.keyCode for cross-browser reasons

Comment: Sorry, wrong Fiddle link should be working now, make sure to click within the Result pane to try it out. Also, I changed to event.which as per your suggestion. Cheers!

Comment: Sorry, Mom told me to hit the sack